# XilinxのISE_S6のインストールができません

Tags: java, windows, fpga

Xilinx_ISE_S6_Win10_14.7_ISE_VMs_0206_1をインストールしようとしたところJavaのエラーによりインストーラが起動せずインストールができません。

リンク先のエラーログのようなエラーが吐かれたのですがJavaには無知のため解決法がわかりません。
助けてください。

エラーログが長くて貼れなかったので以下のリンク先のエラーログを見てください
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s2mSJwqOVJs1niBi2I6kGjLFYtHJ2DHp0Ptd7XlVb18

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ログの以下の辺の情報を元に考えると、'sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2' ファイルとか、
その中の 'getDisplayNameOf' メソッド呼び出し時の、パラメータか、戻り値格納アドレス
あたりのどれかが NULL になっていて、メモリアクセス違反が発生したように見えます。

> ＃ EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000055f26adf, pid=19828, tid=9260
>
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
> Current thread (0x000000001a9da000):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9260, stack(0x000000001ec40000,0x000000001ed40000)]
> siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000
>
> R13={method} {0x000000001d018c40} 'getDisplayNameOf' '(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;' in 'sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2'

ログの情報と共にXILINXのコミュニティフォーラムに質問を出せば良いのではないでしょうか？
[Installation and Licensing](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/bd-p/INSTALLBD)

このフォーラム内を Install Java Windows で検索すると70件くらいQ&Aがあるようです。
[検索結果](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?filter=location&q=Install+Java+Windows&location=forum-board%3AINSTALLBD&collapse_discussion=true)

ご質問とは別のソフトですが、質問に対してVC++のランタイムdllを確認しては？とかコメントされていたり(確認されたか、結果はなんだったかは不明のようですが)、
[Vivado 2015.2 Installer fail](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/Vivado-2015-2-Installer-fail/m-p/866491/highlight/true#M22292)

Javaのランタイムを更新したら動かなくなったという問題で、アプリ側を最新版にしたら動いた。という結果だったりといったQ&Aがあります。
[Did latest Java update break Xilinx SDK 2016.4?](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Installation-and-Licensing/Did-latest-Java-update-break-Xilinx-SDK-2016-4/m-p/806107/highlight/true#M19675)

それと並行して、XILINXのサポート窓口に直接質問するのも良いのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーの原因がなんとなくわかりました。これを機にjavaの勉強もしてみようと思います。Xilinxのほうにも質問してみます。